# Apple Instruments stops working when tracing iOS allocations

Tags: ios, ipad, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xcode-instruments

I'm checking an Xamarin iOS app's memory usage using Instruments' *Allocations* instrument.

I have an issue with Instruments stopping to receive any allocations data just after a short while. I haven't seen any patterns in memory usage, cpu usage, time, or location in the app when the problem is triggered, but most of the times it stops working after about 12 seconds.

It seems like the following is logged in the device log the same moment it stops working:

```
kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: SalesApp(2291) deny(1) process-info-pidinfo 1530
kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: SalesApp(2291) deny(1) sysctl-read kern.proc.pid.1530
```

What could be the problem?

Every time it stops I can stop the recording ant restart it an it runs for a while again.

I have tried restarting everything with no change in behaviour. **I know I had this problem last December, but then on a different version of Xcode, iOS, OS X, Xamarin Studio and I had a different iPad.**

Current versions:

- iOS: 9 beta 5 (13A4325c)
- OS X: Yosemite (10.10.5 (14F27))
- Xcode/Instruments: 6.4 (6E35b)
- Xamarin Studio: 5.9.5 (build 10)
- Deployment target: 7.0

Screenshot from Instruments where the recording stopped right after 7 seconds:
[image: Screenshot from Instruments[1]]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=19379) where an unfortunate interaction between the GC and Instruments causes the process to deadlock.

There are a few (wide) shots you can take to try and make it work:

- Trigger the GC frequently on the main thread by doing this in your FinishedLaunching method:

  ```
  NSTimer.CreateRepeatingScheduledTimer(0.5, (v) => GC.Collect());
  ```
- Try to allocate less memory so that the GC triggers less frequently (I know this is what you're trying to do in the first place)
- Try to do stuff on the main thread only. The deadlock occurs when an Instruments reports an allocation on one thread, while the GC is running on another. If you're only doing work on one thread, the deadlock doesn't occur.
- It's usually random, so sometimes you might get lucky and it doesn't deadlock. IOW just try again and again.

Comment: It seems like you're right. Just interacting with the app not so fast was enough to let me keep profiling it. Also upgrading to Xcode/Instruments 7.0 beta made the problem go away (though that might be a lucky coincidence).

Comment: I'm using XCode 7.1 and still having this issue.  My app is making a lot of API calls (background threads/tasks) and instruments is locking up 100% of the time even when trying the Scheduled timer of garbage collection

Comment: I was able to get around the deadlocks by doing the following:  Update my iPhone to the latest version of iOS 9 (I was one subversion behind).  Do not start the app with Instruments, have the app already running then attach via "running apps" in instruments.  Then Following @RoyS's comment about interacting with the app VERY slowly.  I had to wait about 3-5 seconds between taps or else I'd have deadlocks.  The Garbage Collect trick didn't work for my API call heavy app

Comment: Six years later, Xcode 13 and Xamarin.iOS 15.2.0.17, still the same. My app is doing lots of CoreGraphics calls in tasks and instruments is locking always after a couple of seconds. No ways to get any useful information, where the memory is leaking.  We checked hundred times to make sure not to miss any Dispose, but maybe its also bugs in Xamarin.iOS?